# TFS 2013 Admin Console locks Tfs_Configuration preventing its restoration

Tags: tfs

My dry run attempt to restore a set of TFS databases failed because the admin console reports that Tfs_Configuration already exists and should be dropped before the restore:

```
TF400990: Database Tfs_Configuration exists on SQL instance
```

[image]

However, the admin console has an open connection to the Tfs_Configuration which prevents me from dropping the database. If I close the admin console, perform the drop, and try to re-launch the admin console it fails because it cannot find the Tfs_Configuration database. So I'm stuck.

I can work around by manually restoring the databases or using the tfsrestore.exe tool (but that won't include the logs -- just the full backup).

So how is restore supposed to work from the admin console? My scenario is total vanilla. Install TFS, backup, quiesce, restore... seems like that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Duh. I had to uninstall the application tier first.