# Domain credentials suddenly invalid

Tags: tfs, permissions

I previously had TFS 2017 and SQL 2016 working well on a single 250GB Server 2016  `.VHDX` with two partitions, `C:` and `D:`. SQL is installed on `C:`, with its data directories on `D:`.

Oddly, `C:` started filling up unexpectedly, so I decided to move the `D:` partition to its own `.VHDX` and expand `C:`.

This all went well, and I now have two 100GB `.VHDXs` with `C:` and `D:`, respectively. (This is a one-man shop, so data storage needs are quite small at present. These needs will increase soon, however, so this is another reason to split off into multiples like this.)

The trouble comes when I try to sign in to TFS using the same domain account (`DOMAIN\User`) that worked before all of this took place. I'm now unable to sign in, and I'm prompted for credentials in a continuous loop (unless I cancel the basic auth dialog, in which case I get a `401-Unauthorized`).

I've reapplied all accounts using the TFS Management Console, but this hasn't worked. FYI I'm able to boot to the server desktop and connect to the SQL instance and browse TFS tables using SSMS.

What must I fix to be able to sign in as before?

Comment: What about the new added Domain users? also check if the local (non-domain) users work or not. Have you ever backed up the TFS database before? If yes, try to restore the database, then check it again.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT — Hm, turns out I'm unable to restore. I'm getting `TF400990`/`TF400991` errors during the Readiness Check: *"Database exists."* FYI this is the last I'll be able to respond until the end of the week. I'm in Alaska and the fish are running ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the relationship between TFS and SQL server is destroyed by the partition expanding.

First, please check if there are problems for the SQL Server and TFS databases. If no issues, just try to [Re-RegisterDB](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#registerdb) and [RemapDBs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs) for TFS.

If that still not work, I am afraid that you have to reconfigure the TFS. uninstall the application tier then reinstall it again using the existing database. If the SQL Server and TFS database also have problems, you have to reinstall sql server and restore the backed up data.

Similar thread for your reference : [TFS 2013 Admin Console locks Tfs_Configuration preventing it's restoration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481877/tfs-2013-admin-console-locks-tfs-configuration-preventing-its-restoration)

Comment: I didn't make it to the `RemapDBs` command; `RegisterDB` did the trick. Very good, thank you.